# Making unclickable links on ipodlinux.org clickable using a .js (JavaScript) file

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to make an extension for Firefox that replaces all instances of `a class=` in HTML code on ipodlinux.org with `a href=` using a .js (JavaScript) file to make unclickable links on ipodlinux.org clickable, but can't find any solutions to help me do that. However, I've made the `manifest.json` for the extension, which looks like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 1,
    "name": "iPodLinux +",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Allows all unclickable links to be clicked on.",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*ipodlinux.org*"],
        "js": ["ipodlinuxplus.js"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: But what is your actual code (the `.js` file)?

Comment: I tried different pieces of JavaScript code, but didn't think any of them would work, so I removed them from the .js file. When I posted this reply to you, the .js file, which, including the file extension, is called ipodlinuxplus.js, was empty.

Comment: Could you provide an example page that has some of the links you want to change?

Comment: http://www.ipodlinux.org/Applications/. However, as the description of this question says, I'm trying to make an extension for Firefox that replaces all instances of a class= in HTML code on ipodlinux.org with a href= using a .js (JavaScript) file to make unclickable links on ipodlinux.org clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the links on the page you gave ([ipodlinux.org/Applications](http://www.ipodlinux.org/Applications)), most have the class "external" and the URL in the `title` attribute instead of `href`. This code will fix them:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.external").forEach(function(el) {
  el.href = el.title;
});
```

However, I tried following a number of the links and none of the pages existed anymore, which is probably why the links were disabled in the first place.

Comment: I can't get the extension to work, whether through "Load Temporary Add-on" in the "Add-ons" section of about:debugging, no matter the file (I even tried loading the file as a .zip file), or renaming the file extension to .xpi and trying to open the .xpi file in Firefox through File Explorer. Here's my manifest.json now: {"manifest_version":1,"name":"iPodLinux +","version":"1.0","description":"Allows all unclickable links to be clicked on.","content_scripts":[{"matches":["*://*ipodlinux.org*"],"js":["ipodlinuxplus.js"]}],"applications":{"gecko":{"id":"ipodlinuxplus@example.com"}}}